# 3d flash banner problem?

Tags: php, javascript, html

my problem is -
3d banner fx is over the menu dropdown...i try use the z-index function but not work.
The problem only in internet explorer and chrome but mozila it's ok.
http://www.peckchew.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
<param name=”wmode” value=”transparent”>
```

[Check `wmmode` attribute](http://www.sajithmr.me/wmode-flash-overlapping-problem/).

Comment: i'm using wordpress..i just put this code "<?php fx3dbanner_echo_embed_code(); ?>"to echo the flash banner.How to find the "<param name=”wmode” value=”transparent”>
" in wordpress?

Comment: @Muhammad Read the article linked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the wmode to opaque for it to adhere to z-index rules. Setting to transparent will simply place it above everything else. You may not want this.

Because you're using the Wordpress FX3D plugin you need to edit the plugin file found here: p-content/flashxml/3d-banner-fx/3d-banner-fx.php.

Look for this line (around line 75):

```
<param name="wmode" value="window"></param>
```

and change to

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>
```

Comment: i just put the code under <General_Properties>..but nothing happen?...the problem only in Ie and google chrome...http://www.peckchew.com/

Comment: Can you edit the plugin file directly? It should be in wp-content/flashxml/3d-banner-fx/3d-banner-fx.php. Look for this line "<param name="wmode" value="window"></param>" (around line 75) and change to "<param name="wmode" value="opaque"></param>".